# Expressing area of a parallelogram as sum of areas of two rectangles using determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, area

Say A= $\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           y_{1} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$
and 
 $B=\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{2} \\
           y_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$
 are two *perpendicular* vectors with *unit* length.
I've been trying to understand how the expression $\color{red}{x_1y_2}-\color{grey}{x_2y_1}$ gives the area of the *parallelogram* formed by these vectors. I've started with perpendicular unit vectors for simplicity. 
[image]

Ofcourse area of the *blue* square doesn't change under rotation, but I'm wondering if it's possible to see why the continuously changing areas of *red* and *black* squares add up to the area of *blue* square ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the $x$-axis, in your diagram it can be clearly seen that the width of the red and black squares are defined by the $x$- coordinate of the $\pmb{A}$ vector and the $\pmb{B}$ vector, respectively.

Thus, the side length of the red square is $\cos(a)$.

Similarly, the side length of the black square is $\cos(180-a-90) = \cos(90-a) = \sin(a)$.

Thus, the area of the red square is $\cos^2 a$ and the area of the black square is $\sin^2 a$.

Using the identity $\cos^2a + \sin^2a =1$,

it follows that the sum of the red square and the black square is unity.

Comment: Brilliant! As the angle $a$ increases, $\cos a$ decreases and $\sin a$ increases keeping the sum $\cos^2a + \sin^2a$ constant. I'll see if I can figure something like this for perpendicular non unit vectors. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

$x_2=-y_1$ and $y_2=x_1$ so that $x_1y_2-x_2y_1=x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2=x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2$, the constant area.

The animation also illustrates the theorm of Pythagoras,

$$x_1^2+y_1^2=x_1^2+x_2^2=a^2,\\x_2^2+y_2^2=x_2^1+x_1^2=b^2.$$

Comment: Wow! By same reasoning, when the vectors are not unit, $(x_2,y_2) = (-ky_1,kx_1)$; so $x_1y_2-x_2y_1 = k(x_1^2+y_1^2)$, the constant area. You're awesome! Thank you so much :) I'll try the general case now where the vectors are not perpendicular.

Comment: Ahh sneaky pythagoras! so here the projections of $a$ or $b$ onto $x, y$ axes are the legs and the vectors $a,b$ themselves are the hypotenuse. Nice nice !